# How do I extends a particular types/interface for react bootstrap type definition?

Tags: typescript-typings, react-bootstrap, react-typescript

I tried to somehow extend or so called override the exiting typed definition from react-bootstrap library because I modified the theme and added more spacers / gap which will affect the library.
I'm currently doing Vite React stack.

I tried to extend GapValue types from it by doing;

/src/types/react-bootstrap.d.ts

```
import { GapValue } from 'react-bootstrap';

declare module 'react-bootstrap' {
  export type GapValue = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20;
}
```

This doesn't take any effect at all and still giving me type error "Type '6' is not assignable to type 'GapValue | undefined'."

When I right click on the props of gap in Stack component, and press "Go to implementations", it will still redirect me to the actual Stack.d.ts types from the library instead of the type I created.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a bit tricky actually. You can merge interface declarations but you can't merge type declarations. If you were to merge declaration for an imported interface, you could do as following:

```
declare global {
    namespace YourNamespace{
        interface importedInterface = {addedProperty:string | number}
    }

}
```

the namespace which you should use is visible in declaration files(*.d.ts).